# JWT Angular Authentication on Refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

So I'm following the following Egghead.io guide:
https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-finalizing-jwt-authentication-with-angularjs

With a twist, I am trying to incorporate a MongoDB to retrieve my users. I have everything working so far, except the last part where he states that the /me route should just return req.user and it should be fine on refreshes. I don't get that. What I do get is blank user returned from my server.

My server code is setup like this:

```
var jwtSecret = 'fjkdlsajfoew239053/3uk';

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(expressJwt({ secret: jwtSecret }).unless({ path: [ '/login' ]}));
app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render(__dirname + '/client/bundle.js');
});

app.get('/me', function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.user);
});

... setup for user schema and other boring stuff ...

  function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    var body = req.body;
    if (!body.username || !body.password) {
      res.status(400).end('Must provide username or password');
    }

    //do salting, hashing, etc here yo
    User.findOne({ username: body.username }, function(err, user){
      if (user === null || body.password !== user.password) {
        res.status(401).end('Username or password incorrect');
      }else{
        req.user = user;
        next();
      }
    });
  }

  // ROUTES
  app.post('/login', authenticate, function (req, res, next) {
    var token = jwt.sign({
      username: req.user.username
    }, jwtSecret);
    res.send({
      token: token,
      user: req.user
    });
  });

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

And my controller (Client-side) handling the basic authentication is:

```
module.exports = function($scope, $state, $modal, UserFactory) {
  var vm = this;

  $scope.$state = $state;
  $scope.sign_in = false;

  $scope.open =  function () {
    var $modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'suggestion-modal.html',
      controller: 'modalCtrl'
    });
  };

  // initialization
  UserFactory.getUser().then(function success(response) {
    vm.user = response.data;
  });

  function login(username, password) {
    UserFactory.login(username, password).then(function success(response) {
      vm.user = response.data.user;
    }, handleError);
  }

  function logout() {
    UserFactory.logout();
    vm.user = null;
  }

  function handleError(response) {
    alert('Error: ' + response.data);
  }

  vm.login = login;
  vm.logout = logout;
};
```

Can anyone catch the bug I'm not seeing here? Basically I have a JWT on the client when I'm logged in but my initialization on the client controller is not recognizing that I'm logged in (it's not setting the user object to anything). It's kinda strange.

Comment: The value of `req.user` is set by express-jwt. It is the decoded token. Your authenticate method should not be setting the user, it simply calls the next middleware if the user authenticates properly. Then the next middleware returns the token, which will be decoded by express-jwt into the req.user object on future requests. If you need to look up the use for some reason, you can use the information in req.user to find the use and set it to req.resolvedUser (or whatever you like). Good luck!

Comment: Your a god, thank you for the help! Egghead should pay you more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solution ended up taking into account Kent's help and a little brainstorming. It looked like the following. Note, apparently middleware ordering in express matters a lot since after changing when Express-jwt got loaded made a huge difference in whether or not the authentication headers were checked on initial directory load on the client (which if they were angular wouldn't load and the whole app broke). Cheers!

```
'use strict';
var faker = require('faker');
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
var compression = require('compression');
var express = require('express');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var connectLiveReload = require('connect-livereload');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var app = express();

var jwtSecret = 'fjkdlsajfoew239053/3uk';

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
// app.get('/', function(req, res){
//   res.render(__dirname + '/client/bundle.js');
// });
app.use(expressJwt({ secret: jwtSecret }).unless({ path: ['/login']}));

app.get('/me', function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.user);
});


...schema stuff...

  // UTIL FUNCTIONS

  function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    var body = req.body;
    if (!body.username || !body.password) {
      res.status(400).end('Must provide username or password');
    }

    //do salting, hashing, etc here yo
    User.findOne({ username: body.username }, function(err, user){
      if (user === null || body.password !== user.password) {
        res.status(401).end('Username or password incorrect');
      }else{
        req.user = user;
        next();
      }
    });
  }

  // ROUTES
  app.post('/login', authenticate, function (req, res, next) {
    var token = jwt.sign({
      username: req.body.username
    }, jwtSecret);
    res.send({
      token: token,
      user: req.user
    });
  });

// app.use(connectLiveReload()); figure out whats wrong with this later and get livereload working

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```